# How can I customize serialization of my object such that it changes the property type based on another property's condition?

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, bson

I have a C# .NET object as such:

```
public class CustomField
{
    public int CustomFieldId { get; set; }
    public string PropertyType {get;set;}
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

It is serialized upon insertion into my MongoDB per this method:

```
                _collectionProfiles.InsertOneAsync(profileDocument).Wait();
```

The problem is that this is a generic object.  All of my PropertyValue(s) are not strings.  They are DateTimes, Numbers, etc and are stored as such in the PropertyType.  So the String value of PropertyType could be DateTime, String...

How can I customize the serialization so that I am storing the PropertyValue as a valid DateTime/Number/etc Format in Mongo so that I can use comparison queries (Greater Than, Less Than)?  Right now, everything is just a string and obviously I can only search on exact matches or such.

Comment: I know this is old. but did you try defining PropertyValue as either dynamic or object and assign the correct value while assigning/setting value to PropertyValue.